# доброго времени суток, хочу уточнить правильно ли я понял строчку из кода

Tags: javascript

```
let allModels = {};

function createModel(Model, ...args) {
    let model = new Model(...args);

    model._id = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
    allModels[model._id] = model;

    return model;
}

let user = createModel(class User {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    sayHi() {
        alert(this.name);
    }
}, "Вася");

user.sayHi(); // Вася

alert( allModels[user._id].name ); // Вася
```

`allModels[model._id] = model;` интересует эта строка, правильно я понял, что свойство `model._id` из объекта  `model` скопировали в `allModels`?
спасибо заранее за помощь!!!

Comment: Нет, в объект `allModels` добавили свойство с ключом (названием) равным `model._id` и значением `model`.

Answer (score 1):

> правильно я понял, что свойство `model._id` из объекта `model` скопировали в `allModels`?

Нет, не правильно.

В данной строке

```
allModels[model._id] = model;
```

происходят два действия:

1. Происходит доступ к свойству с именем равным значению `model._id`
2. Указанному свойству присваивается значение `model`

Таким образом объект *allModels* хранит все объекты, которые были созданы с помощью функции *createModel*.